# div does not flex wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new in CSS. I want to move the box div below when the browser is getting smaller or all box position go back column position when the browser is in desktop size. I have added flex-wrap and flex-direction in my source code but nothing happens. I don't know what mistake that I make. Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-top {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.container-top-context {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
}

.container-top-context h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
}

.container-top-context h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  word-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.logo {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-testimony-context {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #EF5350;
  color: #FFCDD2 padding:5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #AB47BC;
  color: #E1BEE7;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #29B6F6;
  color: #B3E5FC;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-4 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #66BB6A;
  color: #C8E6C9;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>my flex box</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-top">
    <div class="container-top-context">
      <h1>Road of Kalibaenan</h1>
      <h2>Gives exact direction to unusual creatures</h2>
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-testimony-context">
    <div class="box-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by `the box div below`?

Comment: what I mean is box-1,box-2,box-3 and box-4 layout inside the container became column position when the browser is getting smaller.

Comment: You have to use `@media` queries for that. i.e: `el {foo: bar}; @media (max-width: 600px) { el { foo: baz} }`. Your `el` will have `foo` set to `bar` on screens wider than `600px` and to `baz` up to `600px`, inclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is flexing as intended, just one at a time and at a very small screen size.

To control this better and make the flex-direction switch at once try using a media query like the updated exampled below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-top {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.container-top-context {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
}

.container-top-context h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
}

.container-top-context h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  word-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.logo {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-testimony-context {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #EF5350;
  color: #FFCDD2 padding:5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #AB47BC;
  color: #E1BEE7;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #29B6F6;
  color: #B3E5FC;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-4 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #66BB6A;
  color: #C8E6C9;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container-testimony-context {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>my flex box</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-top">
    <div class="container-top-context">
      <h1>Road of Kalibaenan</h1>
      <h2>Gives exact direction to unusual creatures</h2>
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-testimony-context">
    <div class="box-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="box-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, late response to your message. I will explore more about media query. Really appreciated your answer, sir. Thank you so much.